# How to login to Coursera using python requests?

Tags: python, authentication, python-requests

I'm trying to login to [coursera](https://www.coursera.org) using python requests. The login [form](https://www.coursera.org/?authMode=login) is loaded dynamically and cannot be accessed using GET. Here's a demonstration:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

with HTMLSession() as sess:
    r = sess.get('https://www.coursera.org/?authMode=login')
    email_xp = '//*[@id="email"]'
    print(r.html.xpath(email_xp))
    r.html.render()
    print(r.html.xpath(email_xp))
```

Which prints:

```
[]
[<Element 'input' data-e2e='login-email-input' placeholder='name@email.com' aria-required='false' id='email' name='email' type='email' class=('css-7dsrhu',)>]
```

How to login using POST and verify that it logged in successfully by accessing a course already available to my account?

```
https://www.coursera.org/learn/course-i-am-enrolled-in/home/week/1
```

Answer (score 0):

Loading the page `https://www.coursera.org/?authMode=login` would return an HTML page with the form in it. If you fill up and submit the form, it would then gather that info into the body of an HTTP POST to a target URL. That is the URL that you need to access, not the HTML page `https://www.coursera.org/?authMode=login`.

If you try to log-in, it forwards your credentials here:

[image]

Thus, you need to perform:

- HTTP Method: POST
- URL: `https://www.coursera.org/api/login/v3`
- Body (based on actual request): `{"email":"email@email.com","password":"thepassword","recaptchaToken":"thetoken","webrequest":true}`

If the response is status code 2xx (e.g. 200), then your login was successful.

You might want to check [coursera-dl](https://github.com/coursera-dl/coursera-dl) which I believe is an API targeted to Coursera. There is also this [open issue](https://github.com/coursera-dl/coursera-dl/issues/777) about the log-in to `https://api.coursera.org/api/login/v3`

Comment: I am unable to get [coursera-dl](https://github.com/coursera-dl/coursera-dl) to work because of the issue you mentioned. By following other related issues, they led me to this [vid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xpy0H4T9zHU) which I followed, and despite some people indicating it works, I got other errors. If you know alternative ways of logging in, please post a complete working example, thanks. I also need clarification on `recaptchaToken` and where i should find it.

Comment: My post just answers the original question `How to login to a dynamic form using python requests`. I would rename the question to be more specific.